# may not be null for IVR_Voice_Trigger

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am new to Twilio IVR. I build the app, but throwing this error while publishing.

may not be null for Trigger
must match a widget name for Trigger

I don't understand the issue. Anyone have experience with this error ?

I just build the app in Twilio studio and got the error